# Bootstrap fixed side bar, chatbar css

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Designing a web page that looks like this

```
----------------------navbar-----------
|sidebar                              |
|                                     |
|        content                     sidechatbox
|                                     |
|                                     |
---------------------------------------
```

i have the side bar on the left and top nav thats fixed. The sidechat box is organized by columns but the column of the sidechat box is not on the complete left of the page, the container never takes up the whole full page, so when I have col-md 8 for content, and col-md4 for the sidechat box there is still some space to the right of it. How can i fix it so its absolutely to the utmost right of the page(current display).

Update:

I have the side bar in the side now, but how to make the chat box a length of the full screen, the input at the bottom, and overflow work is bugging me out. Any idea how to get the chat messages to overflow, while keeping the chat box static? Here is a updated demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/mrcfq4hj/4/

Comment: It would be better for us to understand; if you show what code you have tried so far.

Comment: Please post a complete, working example (HTML/CSS/JS) in a Snippet. [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: did it, added some code, html and css

Comment: Use codeply.com and share here

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mrcfq4hj/1/

Answer (score 0):

After viewing your fiddle you may want to create your own container css it seems that the padding from the .container may be the issue. Ether that or the margin from the .panel.